# BigQuery Bug? Backticks affecting name-spacing

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have a table on BigQuery, `our-project-name.ads.Geo`, which contains a `Geo.CountryCode` column.

Using SELECT `Geo.CountryCode` fails when using `our-project-name`.`ads`.`Geo` because of a naming clash between the column and the table, but this problem doesn't occur when using `our-project-name.ads.Geo`. Are these not meant to be semantically equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but if you run the same query against `project.dataset.table` and `project`.`dataset`.`table`, you can see it won't hit the cache, so there is something going on with the query engine that treats them as distinct inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a small semantical difference here, regarding [implicit alias](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#using_aliases) generated by BigQuery.

When you do `` FROM `proj`.`ds`.`tbl` ``  or `FROM proj.ds.tbl` , the table gets aliased as `tbl`. When you do `` FROM `proj.ds.tbl` ``   the table is aliased as `proj.ds.tbl`.

As you found, if the first part of the identifier matches table alias, it is resolved to table alias rather than field name. But if you inclose full name in back-ticks, the alias is different and does not cause conflict. You can however use full name as alias:

```
select `tmp.Foo`.Foo.Baz FROM `tmp.Foo`;
select Foo.Foo.Baz FROM tmp.Foo;
```

It is also possible to specify alias explicitly to avoid ambiguity, say

```
-- selects whole row as value
select foo from tmp.foo;

-- selects column 'foo' only
select foo from tmp.foo as source_table;

-- selects whole row again
select source_table from tmp.foo as source_table;
```

Comment: Awesome, that's so helpful, thanks so much!